# Limitting the size of a downloading file for my LAN with Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have a LAN and a Ubuntu server as router. Can ***I limit the downloading file size. So that my users cant download huge file sizes***
example: my users should not download more than 100 MB file.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Not at the routing level, but you could put up a web proxy like squid. http://tecexpertz.com/how-to-limit-download-size-in-squid/

Comment: Routing is basically is just ip and ip doesn't care about above layers data it contains or even it's file size. As far as i can see that you have two options. Setup a proxy or limit the maximum file size at the users home directories.